# Return the uniqueidentifier generated by a default on insert

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, default-value, uniqueidentifier

#### Goal

Retrieve the latest guid value in real time after you have inserted the value in the table

#### Problem

Don't know how to do it

#### Info

- The code should only specify new values for *address* and *zipcode*
- There can be lots of data in the table

#### Table

```
CREATE TABLE [AddressBook]
(
    [testID] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL default newid(),
    [address] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [zipcode] [nvarchar](50) NULL
)
```

Comment: I would suggest using NEWSEQUENTIALID() rather than NEWID(), otherwise your clustered index (assuming it's going to be on testID) will become heavily fragmented.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I think you are looking for [output](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177564.aspx)

```
DECLARE @MyTableVar table([testID] [uniqueidentifier]);
 INSERT [AddressBook] ([address], [zipcode])
        OUTPUT INSERTED.[testID] INTO @MyTableVar
 VALUES (N'address', N'zipcode');

--Display the result set of the table variable.
 SELECT [testID] FROM @MyTableVar;

GO
```

uniqueidentifier may not be the most efficient id here but this is an answer to the stated question

Comment: note that `INSERTED.[testID]` is the property of what you want from the row, not the name of the property in `@MyTableVar`

Comment: This pattern effectively uses the Trigger pseudo-tables, so make sure you understand `inserted` and `deleted` scopes and uses before implementing this design pattern.

Comment: @GoldBishop This has nothing to do with triggers: the `OUTPUT` clause has entirely separate `inserted` and `deleted` tables which you can even use outside of a trigger (and if used inside a trigger they will hide the main pseudo-tables)

Comment: @Charlieface then you missed the point of my comment..."..effectively uses..."  As far as behavior, `inserted` and `deleted` have the same behaviors as their Trigger siblings.

Answer (score -3):

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[tbl_Clients](
    [ClientID] [uniqueidentifier] NULL,
    [ClientName] [varchar](250) NULL,
    [ClientEnabled] [bit] NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO

CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_ClientCreate]
@in_ClientName varchar(250) = "New Client 123",
@in_ClientEnabled bit,
@out_ClientId uniqueidentifier OUTPUT
AS

SET @out_ClientId = NEWID();

INSERT
INTO tbl_Clients(ClientId, ClientName, ClientEnabled) 
VALUES(
@out_ClientId, 
@in_ClientName,
@in_ClientEnabled)


DECLARE @return_value int,
        @out_ClientId uniqueidentifier

EXEC    @return_value = [dbo].[sp_ClientCreate]
        @in_ClientName = N'111',
        @in_ClientEnabled = 1,
        @out_ClientId = @out_ClientId OUTPUT

SELECT  @out_ClientId as N'@out_ClientId'

SELECT  'Return Value' = @return_value

GO
```

Result:-59A6D7FE-8C9A-4ED3-8FC6-31A989CCC8DB

Comment: The question asks how to get the value generated by the default constraint. This doesn't answer that question, even though it does provide a workaround

Answer (score -4):

Another way,

```
DECLARE @id varchar(50) = CONVERT(VARCHAR(50), NEWID());

INSERT INTO [yourtable]
( [id])
VALUES
(@id);

SELECT @id;
```

Comment: The question asks how to get the value generated by the `default` constraint.  This doesn't answer that question, even though it does provide a workaround.